# How to set the textfield right-align in the Settings.bundle

Tags: ipad, textfield, alignment, settings.bundle, right-align

I add a TextField in the Settings.bundle, it's text is left align default,but I want to let it right align.How can do that.Please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell types of "Text" (editable) are left aligned and types of "Title" (read-only text) are right aligned.